# Unexpected indention in bibliography items (beamer)

Tags: beamer, biblatex, bibliographies

I have a minimal example where the bibliography entry is intended. I cannot imagine that this is expected behavior. Am I doing something wrong?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex8]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@inproceedings{doe2017,
    title={A really interesting and long title to illustrate the problem},
    author={Doe, John},
    booktitle={Some International Conference on Something Really Interesting},
    pages={100--200},
    year={2017}
}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{mybib}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Publications}
\nocite{doe2017}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: latex output bibliography]

Comment: What indentation are you talking about? The fact that the second and third lines start roughly at the same position as the first line in general? (This would be intentional and is normal for lists in LaTeX.) Or do you mean that there is a slightly misalignment so that the first line starts a tad wider to the right than the other lines? (That probably needs a bit of adjusting and looking at. Not a lot of people seem to be bothered by it, though... otherwise we would have seen more questions about that.)

Comment: I expect that "J" of "John" is properly aligned with "p" of "problem". When I have multiline items in an itemize environment they are also properly aligned and the first line of each item is not shifted a bit to the right.

Comment: Ah OK, I'll have something ready for that in a moment.

Comment: Thanks! That really does the trick. I wonder why this never bothered anyone...

Comment: Well, the space is quite small and if people cite ten or more papers or use a non-numeric style the issue will (probably) not appear because the space reserved for the label is going to be large enough for the icon (though arguably excessive).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to be able to align the lines in the bibliography properly `biblatex` measures the width of all bibliography labels and uses the longest label to set the list parameters.

But by default `beamer` replaces the standard labels that `biblatex` would output with its little icons. Those icons may have a slightly different width than the actual labels and so small misalignments can occur in the first line of the bibliography entry if the icon is wider than the calculated label (on the other hand the left margin might be excessive in case the calculated length is far larger than the icon width).

I have reported the issue at https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/531 to discuss a better (hopefully automatic) solution, but in the meantime you can set the relevant `biblatex`-calculated width manually (or rather you can manually set a minimum value). After a look at the [`beamer` sources](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/blob/04b25165835abcbe39294c9f5d89c371c70ba8c3/base/themes/inner/beamerinnerthemedefault.sty#L16) `14pt` looks like a good minimum value.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\setlength{\labelnumberwidth}{14pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Publications}
\nocite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: Before]

[image: After]